Is a "recursive" quadrature known in the literature that chooses the integrated intervals according to some error criterion?
We know that

we can integrate an interval as if we were integrating parts of it separately, as well as those parts as if they were smaller intervals, recursively,

each numerically integrated interval has distinct deviation from others and choosing which ones to refine is also choosing which deviations we will try to repair and

there are probably some known methods that take advantage of this.


So I want to know what these methods are. Are there recursive quadratures in the literature?

I might start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_quadrature

I think , the Romberg method comes next to what you want.

You might also have a look at the discussions in the Quadpack (Piessens, et al.) manual.

As our friend Eric Towers said, this is like a adaptive quadrature but I haven't found any specific that satisfied me yet when I searched and we can also try to create some method according to some principles. I will gradually develop a line of reasoning in this answer and welcome suggestions. Yes, I plan on adding more.
General directives
According to adaptive quadrature wikipedia page, we have something like $I=∫f(x)dx$ (exact), $Q≈I$ (approach), $D=Q-I$ (deviation), $E=|D|$ (error), $T≥0$ (error tolerance) and a fact: adaptive quadrature follows the general scheme "while E>T break interval", therefore the amount of intervals (and calculations that occur) depends on the measured error. Of course, you can also use this to choose the intervals you'll break until you reach a tolerated limit.
Don't forget that if an interval has a tolerated error of estimation and is divided in $n$ equal subintervals, it's advisable that the tolerance of each subinterval is also the original interval's tolerance divided by $n$, so that the accumulation of errors corresponds to that of the original interval.

In the field of computing, there is greater familiarity with the heap (specific tree structure). It stores elements according to some ordering criterion that allows quick access to the first (or last) element. If there is an estimate of the error reduction of breaking an interval, we can choose the candidate that we expect to be most beneficial using heap.

Options
The problem is that we calculate approximations using quadratures because we won't calculate the exact value (error too). So we are forced to estimate the error. How? There must be endless ways and one of them is to compare quadratures/granularities results (that must be endless ways too).
Variating quadratures
An example case is when calculating using Simpson's rule (error degree 4), if you use the same values ​​to calculate using the trapezoidal and rectangle rule (error degree 2) you can compare errors of different degrees and/or assume that where using more points made a bigger difference it's probably better to refine more.
$\int_a^bf(x)dx≈R=(b-a)*f(\frac{a+b}{2})$
$\int_a^bf(x)dx≈T=(b-a)*(f(a)+f(b))/2$
$|T-R|=|(b-a)*(f(a)-2f(\frac{a+b}{2})+f(b))|/2$ >> R to T: points +1, error degree +0
$\int_a^bf(x)dx≈S=(b-a)*(f(a)+4f(\frac{a+b}{2})+f(b))/6$
$|S-R|=|(b-a)*(f(a)-2f(\frac{a+b}{2})+f(b))|/6$ >> S to R: points +2, error degree +2
$|S-T|=|(b-a)*(f(a)-2f(\frac{a+b}{2})+f(b))|/3$ >> S to T: points +1, error degree +2
$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^\frac{a+b}{2}f(x)dx+\int_\frac{a+b}{2}^bf(x)dx≈T_2=(b-a)*(f(a)+2f(\frac{a+b}{2})+f(b))/4$
$|T_2-T|=|(b-a)*(f(a)-2f(\frac{a+b}{2})+f(b))|/4$ >> points/intervals +1
$|S-T_2|=|(b-a)*(f(a)-2f(\frac{a+b}{2})+f(b))|/12$ >> error degree +2
Just trapezoidal rule
We can also calculate the function values at same three points: $f(a)$, $f((a+b)/2)$ and $f(b)$. Using these values, we can approximate the integral twice using the trapezoidal rule (once with one interval and once with two equal-sized intervals). Then, we can recursively:
(1) calculate $f((3a+b)/4)$ e $f((a+3b)/4)$,
(2) use all five points to calculate a third, more refined approximation of the integral using the trapezoidal rule with four equal-sized intervals and
(3) estimate the error of the third approximation (or another approximation using the three) and check if it's within the tolerance.
(3.1) If so, return the result.
(3.2) Otherwise, recursively calculate the sum of the integrals on $[a,(a+b)/2]$ and $[(a+b)/2,b]$, repeating step (1) for each subinterval, taking advantage of the previously calculated function and integral values.
Alternatively, we can maintain a heap of intervals that would be calculated recursively. We process the intervals with the largest estimated errors until the worst error be within the tolerance or the iteration limit is reached.
Alternatively too, you can shorten the method by starting a recursion with function values for a single integral and then subdividing interval to obtain a second and better estimate. The absolute difference can be used as the error. However, only two approximations are used to estimate the error, and I believe a more accurate error estimate and a better integral approximation can be obtained using three integrals.
Just rectangle rule
Furthermore, the approach that required the fewest points involved increasing the number of three pre-calculated points by two per recursion because it divides one interval in two inserting one midpoint. However, this method evaluates the function at the endpoints, a closed interval.
If we want to integrate over open intervals while maintaining uniform subintervals for a unique rule, the minimum number of points I found was increasing three points by six using rectangle rule. This requires evaluating the function at one interval with one midpoint, dividing with a left and a right point becoming three intervals midpoints and again divides two more per interval, nine points within nine intervals.
Just other rule
Realize that there are countless ways to recursively integrate intervals using one or more rules. If you aim to maximize the reuse of function values in newly calculated ones during recursion using only a quadrature rule, consider the following:

Granularity improves when there's at least one old (initially, there's a granularity to enhance) and one new point per interval.
Dividing a trapezoid into two equal parts yields 2 old points for every 1 new point.
If new points are placed between old ones to maintain the rule, then number of old points is new points plus one (the maximum is a trapezoid).
For open intervals, you can add two more points (before the first old point and after the last old point) or
plan an interval with a midleft and a midright calculated points to each half interval have one and gain one more point instead of two (1 old point per 1 new point).

Therefore, based on these criteria, the optimal choices that I know are

the trapezoidal rule and
$(b-a)*(f((2a+b)/3)+f((a+2b)/3))/2$ rule (because it becomes $(b-a)*(f((5a+b)/6)+f((2a+b)/3)+f((a+2b)/3)+f((a+5b)/6))/4$ that is two intervals same rule).

